# alter rename database syntax error inside transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two databases `prod_db` and `prod_db_new` and I want to rename both or none. I figured a transaction would suit this case:

```
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE prod_db     RENAME TO prod_db_old
ALTER DATABASE prod_db_new RENAME TO prod_db
COMMIT;
```

However, I get syntax error near prod_db_old when run through CLI. What am I missing here ?

Comment: No `;` after each `ALTER DATABASE` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need after all comnands a semicolon

```
BEGIN;
ALTER DATABASE prod_db     RENAME TO prod_db_old;
ALTER DATABASE prod_db_new RENAME TO prod_db;
COMMIT;
```